# NullPointerException when scrolling fast with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have been told to use an AsyncTask here: [nullpointerexception-when-scrolling-fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937264/nullpointerexception-when-scrolling-fast)
Thats what I did but I'm still getting the same error:
It works fine until I start scrolling fast. When scrolling very slow this error doesn't occur. It's really confusing me.

```
package com.mamlambo.tutorial.tutlist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class TutListActivity extends Activity {

    private DatabaseManager mHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatenbank;
    private ArrayList<String> devicesList;
    ListView listView;
    EfficientAdapter objectAdapter;

    private class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Bitmap mIcon1;
        private Bitmap mIcon2;

        private TreeSet mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet();

        private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
        private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
        private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
            // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            // Icons bound to the rows.
            mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
            mIcon2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return devicesList.size();
        }

        public void addItem(final String item) {
            devicesList.add(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public void notifyDataSetChanged() // Create this function in your adapter class
        {
            super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
            devicesList.add(item);
            // save separator position
            mSeparatorsSet.add(devicesList.size() - 1);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls
            // to findViewById() on each row.
            ViewHolder holder;

            // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
            // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
            // by ListView is null.
            int type = getItemViewType(position);

            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                switch (type) {
                    case TYPE_ITEM:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                        // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
                        // we want to bind data to.
                        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Title_List_Item);
                        holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Delete_List_Item);
                        break;
                    case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.seperator_item, null);
                        holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Text_Seperator_Item);
                        break;
                }

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
                // and the ImageView.
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView.findViewById(R.id.Title_List_Item).setTag(devicesList.get(position));
                    convertView.findViewById(R.id.Delete_List_Item).setTag(devicesList.get(position));

                    holder.text.setText(devicesList.get(position));
                    holder.icon.setImageBitmap((position & 1) == 1 ? mIcon1 : mIcon2);

                    holder.text.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener);
                    holder.icon.setOnClickListener(mOnIconClickListener);
                    break;
                 case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                     holder.text.setText(devicesList.get(position));
                     break;
            }

            return convertView;
        }


        private OnClickListener mOnTitleClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(v.getTag().toString() == "ADD DEVICE"){
                        Intent addDevice = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), addDevice.class);
                        startActivity(addDevice);
                    }else{
                        Intent showRemote = new Intent(TutListActivity.this, Remote.class);
                        showRemote.putExtra("selectedDevice", v.getTag().toString());
                        startActivity(showRemote);
                    }
            }
        };

        private OnClickListener mOnIconClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String NameOfDevice[] = new String[2];
                NameOfDevice = v.getTag().toString().split(",");
                mDatenbank.execSQL("DELETE FROM addedDevices WHERE name = '"+NameOfDevice[0]+"'");

                ladeDevices();
                objectAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView text;
            ImageView icon;
        }
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

        mHelper = new DatabaseManager(this);
        mDatenbank = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        objectAdapter = new EfficientAdapter(this);

        new LoadDevices().execute();

    }


    private class LoadDevices extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            devicesList = new ArrayList<String>();
            Cursor devicesCursor = mDatenbank.query("addedDevices", new String[] {"name", "hersteller"}, null, null, null, null, null);
            startManagingCursor(devicesCursor);
            devicesCursor.moveToFirst();

            for (int i=0;i<devicesCursor.getCount();i++){ 
                String addingElement = new String(devicesCursor.getString(0)+", "+devicesCursor.getString(1));
                objectAdapter.addItem(addingElement);
                devicesCursor.moveToNext();
                if (i % 4 == 0) {
                    objectAdapter.addSeparatorItem("separator " + i);
                }
            } 
            objectAdapter.addItem("ADD DEVICE");

            return "All Done!";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            listView.setAdapter(objectAdapter);
        }
    }



    private void ladeDevices() {
        }

}
```

Heres the Logcat Output:

```
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at com.mamlambo.tutorial.tutlist.TutListActivity$EfficientAdapter.getView(TutListActivity.java:152)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:636)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5040)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3197)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3471)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7127)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2170)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1905)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1925)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1379)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3174)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3119)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4134)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4226)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:163)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4205)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4245)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:523)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-10 21:46:04.891: E/AndroidRuntime(5815):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat stack trace for the exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NullPointerException when scrolling fast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937264/nullpointerexception-when-scrolling-fast). Please don't reask the question, edit the initial one. `notifyDataSetChanged` should be called from the main UI thread.

Comment: What is line 152 of TutListActivity.java? As there is where the `NullPointerException` comes from.

Comment: of course... 'NullPointerException when scrolling fast' was my question. Read the description. I just changed the code but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It's this line:               convertView.findViewById(R.id.Title_List_Item).setTag(devicesList.get(position));

Comment: You should print out the values (or use a debugger) of `convertView`, `convertView.findViewById(R.id.Title_List_Item)` and `devicesList` to find out which is `null`.

Comment: either `convertView`, `deviceList`, or the return of `findViewById` are null at this point

Comment: devicesList is not null at any point and how could the return of findViewById be null? Seems like convertView is the problem... Any solution for fixing this?

Comment: I checked everything and as far as I can tell nothing becomes null at the moment the exception occurs. Does anybody have any suggestions? It's really driving me nuts...