# How to make docx preview in imageview android

Tags: android

I need to make preview of doxc file into my image view. I found such libraries as `Docx4j` , but i did not found any possibility of preview creating. What is the easiest way to create preview of doxc? Besides put it in webView

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code for generating a `.docx` or related files thumbnail while displaying them onto the [Webview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView). 
You can show a loader inside your [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView) and load the image using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Gilde](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), or other libraries. 
You can also generate the thumbnail in a [background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695850/android-listview-updating-of-image-thumbnails-using-asynctask-causes-view-recycl) (that is recommended) with [WeakReference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference) of the ImageView object and then display that thumbnail in your designated ImageView.

**Approach**
Just take the snapshot of the Webview after loading the `.docx` file and display it in your designated ImageView.

**Code**

```
//Bitmap Utility
public final class BitmapUtil{
    public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width , height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
        v.draw(c);
        return b;
    }
}

//Then You can call this in Your Activity/Fragment's 'onCreate(...)' or 'onCreateView(...)' method:
setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_FILE);
w = findViewById(R.id.YOUR_WEBVIEW_ID);
w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        try {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapUtil.loadBitmapFromView(view, 100, 100);
            YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            Log.e("YOUR_TAG", "Error occurred while taking snapshot of webview!, Error = "+e.toString());
        }
    }
});

w.loadUrl("http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=android");
```

Edit:
You can convert your .docx file to html using this example: https://github.com/orient33/androidDocxToHtml 
Here is the sample activity:
https://github.com/orient33/androidDocxToHtml/blob/aaaaa/app/src/main/java/com/singuloid/docx2html/DocxShow.java

I hope this helps

Comment: Do i need to import this library? Because here's a lot of Box library files

Comment: where do i have to set path to my file? in `loadUrl("path")` ?

Comment: You can do that in your `onCreate(...)` method of your desired Activity or on `onCreateView(...)` method of your desired Fragment.

Comment: okey, i understand, but do i need to set path in `loadUrl()` method?

Comment: Well, webView can not open doxc files