# Images jumble up in ListView using AsyncTask

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, android-asynctask

I am loading images directly from mp3's and displaying them along with song title in my app. To smoothen the process I am using an AsyncTask and loading the images in background. If i scroll slowly the images appear in correct order with song. However , if I scroll up and down fast , then the images jumble up for 2-3 seconds (as in appear in an incorrect order). After 2-3 seconds the order again becomes normal. How can I avoid this ? Here is my code :

```
public class TestAcitivity extends SherlockListActivity  {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        Uri sourceUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String [] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID};
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, sourceUri,proj,
                                                        null, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
        ListView lv = getListView();//(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        lv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, cursor, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER));
    }
}
class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE));
        String album_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
        TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        text.setText(title);
        if(Long.valueOf(album_id)>0)
        {
            Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, Integer.valueOf(album_id));
            new MyImageLoader(context,view).execute(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        //bindView(v, context, cursor);
        return v;
    }
    private class MyImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Bitmap>{
        Context context;
        View view;
        MyImageLoader(Context context,View view){
            this.context = context;
            this.view = view;
        }
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Uri... uri) {

            ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = res.openInputStream(uri[0]);
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap artwork = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

            return artwork;

        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp){
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            if(bmp!=null)
                iv.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 100, 100, false));
        }
    }
}
```

I am using a custom `CursorAdapter` with loading bitmaps in `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to what is controlling the sort-order of the list being affected by the asynchronous updates.  It could be rapid changes in size of the list items confusing the rendering code for the list view.  One suggestion is to add a default (possibly black) image to each list item straight off that is the same size.  Then as the real images come in, just replace the black ones.

---

**Edit**: It seems that this problem is caused by Android recycling the ViewItem/row and that confusing things with an asynchronous task.  See this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832944/android-load-asynchronous-pictures-in-listview) for more detail and a couple of solutions.

Comment: can u tell how to add default black image?

Comment: Use gimp to create a black image of the size you want, add this to your resources directory.  Create a Bitmap from this image at startup and hold a single reference to it.  In your code where you create the "MyImageLoader"  class, set this Bitmap in the view for the current row.

Comment: I have already set a default image source in the XML of my row. When i scroll , it gets replaced by other items and finally by its own correct image . So i think this wouldnt help

Answer (score 0):

Hack_on is correct. One of the Andorid engineers discusses this problem in a blog bost:

> However, a ListView-specific behavior reveals a problem with our
>   current implementation. Indeed, for memory efficiency reasons,
>   ListView recycles the views that are displayed when the user scrolls.
>   If one flings the list, a given ImageView object will be used many
>   times. Each time it is displayed the ImageView correctly triggers an
>   image download task, which will eventually change its image. So where
>   is the problem? As with most parallel applications, the key issue is
>   in the ordering. In our case, there's no guarantee that the download
>   tasks will finish in the order in which they were started. The result
>   is that the image finally displayed in the list may come from a
>   previous item, which simply happened to have taken longer to download.
>   This is not an issue if the images you download are bound once and for
>   all to given ImageViews, but let's fix it for the common case where
>   they are used in a list.

Here's the link, where he also offers a solution:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Comment: Hi Luke, for posterity, it would be good if you could summarise the solution, so that when the link inevitably dies, your post will still have value.